# Universal Feed Parser

Tags: python

What is the use of a Universal Feed Parser. I want to know because in the stats section of my blog, I see a browser as universalfeedparser. Does that mean someone is tracking my website? Sorry for asking such a basic question but I'm not from an IT background!

Comment: Please mark my answer as right if I answered your question (the green tick) :-)

Answer (score 3):

Universal Feed Parser is a RSS-Parser.
You can read more about RSS here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS

> Rich Site Summary (RSS) [...] is a family of web feed formats used to
>   publish frequently updated works—such as blog entries, news headlines,
>   audio, and video—in a standardized format. An RSS document (which is
>   called a "feed", "web feed", or "channel") includes full or summarized
>   text, plus metadata such as publishing dates and authorship.

That means: with and RSS-Feed you can get a websites content in a standardized view without the websites unique design.

For example: As a user you can use a RSS Reader to follow different blogs and see the updates without the need to surf every blog and check manually for updates. This is a web-based RSS-Reader called [FeedBin](https://feedbin.me).
[image: Web-RSS reader Feedbin]
In the first column there are the different blogs the user follow, in the second the posts and in the third the selected post.

There are a lots of diffrent feed parsers:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_feed_aggregators

The parser you mean:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/feedparser/

If you use a blogging-software like WordPress your site automatically has an RSS-feed. Open `your-domain.com/feed` in your browser.